# How to store facebook profile picture into Parse user table?

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I want to store the facebook profile picture into the parse user table.
Currently i'm trying this:

```
URL img_value = null;
try {
    img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+user.getId()+"/picture?type=small");
} catch (MalformedURLException e){
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);                                  
    Bitmap dp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
    Log.i(IntegratingFacebook.TAG, "image retrieved from facebook");                                     
    // Save the user profile info in a user property
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();     
    if(dp!=null){
       ParseFile saveImageFile= new ParseFile("profilePicture.jpg",compressAndConvertImageToByteFrom(dp));
       currentUser.put("profilePicture",saveImageFile);
    }
    currentUser.saveInBackground();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The URL is right. However dp is always null.
Therefore the image is never stored in the parse user table.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the Url you are using is correct ?

Comment: Yes, you can check it out yourself by placing your id in place of user.getId()!!

Comment: Try and hardcode a FB id instead of using the user.getId() (I suspect your user is null or it returns invalid id) and tell me if it still empty

Comment: I tried that..dp still turns out to be null, also the user.getId() does return a valid id indeed as i'm using it else where in my app and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct **EXCEPT** for the fact that all calls to `graph.facebook.com` should be over SSL.  switch your `http` to `https` and you should be good to go.

This is assuming that you are in a facebook callback were the user object is not a `ParseUser` object because `FacebookUserObject.getId()` and `ParseUserObject.getId()` will obviously return different results.  If you are in a Facebook callback from a request like `Request.newMeRequest()` then your code will work by simply changing the protocol to `https`.  If you are not in a facebook callback and the user object is a `ParseUser` object then you will want to use something like `user.getString("facebookId")` where `facebookId` is a value you've saved in a previous step (perhaps during initial registration).

Comment: I modified my answer.  Your code is correct except for the fact that you are trying to make an HTTP call to a service that only allows connections over SSL.  Just switch your http to https and the rest will work.  I just tested it and it works after that slight modification.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are going about doing it is very messy and might break sometime in the future... BUT have you ever heard of Picasso.

Make sure your URL is good (logcat), grab the picasso library for Android and change this:

```
Bitmap dp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

into this ( try/catch needed )

```
Bitmap dp = Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(URL).get();
```

and you should be good to go!